# Remove numbers and commas inside parenthesis (regex)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to extract the numbers inside this test vector.

I've already tried this:

```
test <- c("(15, 80)","(100, 60)","(40, 40)","(30, 20)","(10, 60)")
stringr::str_extract(test, "[0-9:0-9:0-9], [0-9:0-9:0-9]")
```

But return the same input. I need an output like this:
 `"15, 80"    "100, 60"    "40, 40"    "30, 20"    "10, 60"`

Comment: In your needed output only the parenthesis are removed but not the *commas*. Should the commas stay where they are or should something done with them, or do you need the numbers extracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
 str_remove_all(test, "[()]")
[1] "15, 80"  "100, 60" "40, 40"  "30, 20"  "10, 60"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex replacement approach with `gsub()` we can try:

```r
test <- c("(15, 80)","(100, 60)","(40, 40)","(30, 20)","(10, 60)")
output <- gsub("^\\(|\\)$", "", test)
output

[1] "15, 80"  "100, 60" "40, 40"  "30, 20"  "10, 60"
```

Comment: Or perhaps `output <- gsub("[()]", "", test)`

Answer (score 2):

In this case `trimws` would work.

```
trimws(test, whitespace = "[()]")
#[1] "15, 80"  "100, 60" "40, 40"  "30, 20"  "10, 60"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `trimws` along with `chartr`

```
> trimws(chartr("()", "  ", test))
[1] "15, 80"  "100, 60" "40, 40"  "30, 20"  "10, 60"
```